# find element by object value inside data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following situation.
Have input, which has object in data attribute:

```
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}' value='value 1' />
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}' value='value 2' />
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}' value='value 3' />
```

Is there any selector, without loop, to find all element in document, without adding new data attribute (data-group_id = '1') where:

testname > repeat > group_id = 1

Comment: why not simply create a attribute named group_id ?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question, but would it be possible to add another `data-` attribute like `data-group-id="1"`?

Comment: Yes, another attribute i know, is solution, but still..... is there way like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something with `filter()`

```
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : {"group_id" : 1}}' value='value 1' /><input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : {"group_id" : 1}}' value='value 1' />
 var el =  $('[data-testname]').filter(function() {
  var data = $(this).attr('data-testname');
       if(JSON.parse(data).repeat.group_id  == 1)
             return this;
    });
console.log(el[0])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enz70ud7/

Comment: Better to use `try...catch` to wrap `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, another attribute i know, is solution, but still..... is there way like this?

Yes, you can use attribute-value selector

```
input[data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}']
```

```css
input[data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}'] {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}' value='value 1' />
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}' value='value 2' />
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}' value='value 3' />


<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "2"}"}' value='value 1' />
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "3"}"}' value='value 2' />
<input type='text' data-testname='{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "4"}"}' value='value 3' />
```

I'll recommend to use `data-*` attribute as follow

```
<input type='text' data-group-id="1" value='value 1' />
<input type='text' data-group-id="1" value='value 2' />
<input type='text' data-group-id="1" value='value 3' />
```

And then use attribute-value selector

```
input[data-group-id="1"]
```

```css
input[data-group-id="1"] {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' data-group-id="1" value='value 1' />
<input type='text' data-group-id="1" value='value 2' />
<input type='text' data-group-id="1" value='value 3' />

<input type='text' data-group-id="2" value='value 2' />
<input type='text' data-group-id="3" value='value 3' />
<input type='text' data-group-id="4" value='value 4' />
```

Comment: thank you for your help, the given solution for css is perfect : ) "madalin ivascu" - method was more suitable for me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses `css` selectors. There are no selectors for `json` encoded data for `data` attributes. However, you can try something like this

```
$('input[data-testname=\'{"repeat" : "{"group_id" : "1"}"}"\']').
```

I recommend you to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for a cleaner code:

```
query = $('input').filter(function() {
  var json = JSON.parse($(this).data('testname'));
  return json.repeat.group_id == 1;
});

// Do whatever you want with 'query' jQuery object.
```